# How to backup entire disk for Ubuntu Server quickly and easily

Tags: server, partitioning, backup, dd, disk-image

I want to create an image of Ubuntu Server installation so that when I need to create a new server I can really quickly install the image on a new USB drive.

I was planning to use DD for this but my server installation is split over around 5-7 partitions. As far as I understand it I would have to create these 7 partitions at the correct size then DD each partition one by one.

I really want a solution that will backup all partitions and then create and restore all the partitions each time I want to setup a new server.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any disk imaging utility.
I prefer 
[Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org). It's a Linux based disk imaging utility. You can back up any system you want. It has many features such as cloning a partition or cloning an entire disk.

Answer (score 0):

I would use *dump* for this task. Check [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/ext4backup) documentation to see how it works.
You can use *fdisk* to automate the creation of partition scheme using a script (check command "O" for this purpose).